# SQL is connected but can't run query with php

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $host="43.42.157.14";
$port=3307;
$user="admin";
$password="password";
$dbname="test";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port)
or die ('Could not connect to th e database server' . mysqli_connect_error());
if (!$con->connect_error) {
echo "connect successfully"."<br>";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.calls";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['id_call'];
    }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

After execute this code, Result is "connect successfully" and "0 results";

In phpmyadmin sql query works! What's wrong???

Comment: you sure you are using port 3307?

Comment: Have you checked for errors occuring in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: I redirect 3307 to 3306 and connection works

Comment: Nico yes but error array is empty

Comment: connection refused means you are having a problem with the connection string, it is either the server IP or the PORT, try using port 3306 for testing.

Comment: Are you on localhost?

Comment: You should never publish passwords and usernames, even if they are only for development.

Comment: Maybe you have the same table in two or more different schemas and you're not using the right one?